# WCF : getting a http 400 bad request error

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf, service

I am having this issue and I looked in all the web and saw lots of answers but nothing helped me.

My issue is that every time I make a `GET` from the WCF service, I get a Http 400 bad request response - but when I run the WCF test client, it works fine.

I am using vs 2015.

My config file (which VS generated automatically) is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IProductService" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/Test/Service1/"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IProductService"
        contract="ServiceReference.IProductService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IProductService" />
    </client>
    <services>
      <service name="Test.ProductService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Test.IProductService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/Test/Service1/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="modelEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Products.csdl|res://*/Products.ssdl|res://*/Products.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=localhost;initial catalog=test;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

The service is:

```
public interface IProductService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,UriTemplate = "/GetProducts")]
    List<Product> GetProducts();
}
```

This is the implement method:

```
public List<Product> GetProducts()
{
    modelEntities context = new modelEntities();
    var productEntity = (from p in context.productEntities select p);

    List<Product> products = new List<Product>();

    foreach (var item in productEntity)
    {
        products.Add(TranslateProductEntityToProduct(item));
    }

    return products;
}
```

I was trying without the webinvoke, also tried webget, and also try to replace the basichttpbinding with webbinding.

I looked for many answers here and on the net and nothing helped me

I hope you can help me.

Thanks

Comment: Can u please share complete error from Browser console's network tab ?

Comment: there is no error on console only on network 400 bad requset

Comment: Bad requets occurs either data in incorrect or there is exception in code. You don't have paramters so there must be error in code.

Comment: @Leopard but how can i get products with the wcf test client? and not when i use postman or just url get

Comment: Can this service be browsed from browser directly ?

Comment: no its cant (only start)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121164/discussion-between-erez-and-leopard).